# Gulp module in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

Is there a module that is able to install gulp files, like is possible for [npm](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/npm_module.html):

> ```
> description: Install "coffee-script" node.js package.
> - npm: name=coffee-script path=/app/location
>
> description: Install "coffee-script" node.js package on version 1.6.1.
> - npm: name=coffee-script version=1.6.1 path=/app/location
>
> description: Install "coffee-script" node.js package globally.
> - npm: name=coffee-script global=yes
>
> description: Remove the globally package "coffee-script".
> - npm: name=coffee-script global=yes state=absent
>
> description: Install "coffee-script" node.js package from custom registry.
> - npm: name=coffee-script registry=http://registry.mysite.com
>
> description: Install packages based on package.json.
> - npm: path=/app/location
>
> description: Update packages based on package.json to their latest version.
> - npm: path=/app/location state=latest
>
> description: Install packages based on package.json using the npm installed with nvm v0.10.1.
> - npm: path=/app/location executable=/opt/nvm/v0.10.1/bin/npm state=present
> ```

At the moment the following snippet:

```
- command: /usr/local/lib/npm/bin/gulp
  args:
    chdir: "{{ project_dir }}"
```

is used to install gulp packages, but is it possible to do it as follows?

```
description: Install packages based on package.json.
- gulp: path=/app/location
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the documentation and ansible modules, the answer now seems to be **"no"**. You need to use the Ansible `command` module.

A similar, but unrelated question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003114/how-to-run-global-npm-binaries-with-ansible). Until someone writes a gulp module for Ansible, you need to interact with it via the command or shell modules.